# Join tables query failed with error code- Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'XYZ' to data type tinyint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

I'm facing an issue while trying to join two tables.I have checked the data types are same at both the tables still the error related to data types conversion is shown. Error details are below:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'A00.0' to data type tinyint.

Join query that I used is as below:

```
SELECT table1.column1,table1.column2,table2.column1
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.matching_column = table2.matching_column;
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You're trying to join on columns of different datatypes... how do you expect that to work? Clearly one is a string and the other a number - thats not going to join.

Comment: Make sure that datatype of `table1.matching_column = table2.matching_column` is the same.

Comment: We need to see the table definitions, some sample data, and have the join logic clarified in order to assist.

Answer (score 0):

You have two column of different data type  ..  one is a string and one is a int 
the join   (impilcitally ) convert a string in a INT but this fails

if you can't change the data struct for adding same data type to the involved  columns  .. try convert int to string

```
  SELECT table1.column1,table1.column2,table2.column1
  FROM table1 
  LEFT JOIN table2
  ON table1.matching_column = cast(table2.matching_column,as varchar(32) ) ;
```

or

```
  SELECT table1.column1,table1.column2,table2.column1
  FROM table1 
  LEFT JOIN table2
  ON cast(table1.matching_column,as varchar(32) ) = table2.matching_column ;
```

Comment: It seems to me that the OP should change the data type of them in the designer or update query to adjust data structure of table

Comment: @Phong I agree with you if the user can surely it is better to have the same type of data but if he cannot then he can try to convert the value

Comment: Yes, sir. So the OP should provide us more details.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, you are matching two columns that do not have the same type.  You should fix the types!

In this case, I recommend converting to numbers, rather than strings.  This is because I have been bitten by leading zeros in the past -- the strings are not the same but the numbers are.

In SQL Server, use `try_cast()`:

```
SELECT table1.column1, table1.column2, table2.column1
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN
     table2
     ON table1.matching_column = try_cast(table2.matching_column as tinyint);
```

Of course, this assumes that `table2` has the string column.